# How to push object into array object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

```
import {Plan} from './plan.model';

export class PlanService{

  private plans:Plan[]=[
    new Plan("5:00","reading"),
    new Plan("6:00","writing"),
    new Plan("7:00","cleaning")
  ];

  getPlan(){
    return this.plans.slice();//returns the plan 
  }

  setPlan(time,plan){
    this.plans.push(new Plan(time,plan));
  } 
}
```

---

I have tried above to push the new Plan object into the defined array but this is not working.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Can you try to define the Plans in the constructor? `private plans: Plan[]; constructor() { this.plans.push(new Plan("5:00", "reading"); ...}`

Comment: Show us where do you call `setPlan` method.

Comment: Actually in your last line where you are pushing in `plans`, in this line your code whcih is `(new plan(time, plan))` and in this line compiler treating `plan` as a function and when you open console you will find issue plan is not defined. and i think you need to change your array structure and go with objects.

Comment: What is error saying?

Comment: @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }).                                                                                 i had forgot to make poemService, a provider to other  components. Actually, there isn't a wrong in pushing a new object. and thank guys, for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you,

```
`setPlan(time,plan){
this.plans.push(new plan(){time : time , plan : plan})
};`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.

Comment: Ok..Thanks...!!